# jquery sortable with regexp

Tags: regex, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out the right regexp to match on list item id's.

For example:

```
<ul id="MyList" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id="id=1-32">Item 1</li>
    <li id="id=2_23">Item 2</li>
    <li id="id=3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="id=4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="id=5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="id=6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

On the serialize method, I want it to pull everything after the equal sign (=).  For example, for the first item I need the id to be 1-32, for the second I need it to be 2_23.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#MyList, #OtherList").sortable({
            connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
            update: function () {
                $("#MyListOrder").val($("#MyList").sortable('serialize', { regexp: '/(.+)[=](.+)/)' }));
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

I tried the above, but that didn't quite work.  My regexp expression is wrong and I don't know what it should be.  Ideas?

**UDPATE:**
Instead of using the serialize method, I decided to use toArray.  That way I get the whole ID and can rip out the part I don't want server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the specs, the option should be named "expression", and you don't need the `/.../` in the string, unless you pass a regular expression. This works:

```
.sortable('serialize', { expression: '(.+)=(.+)' })
```

or:

```
.sortable('serialize', { expression: /(.+)=(.+)/ })
```

Working Example: http://jsbin.com/oqejo3/2

Comment: Didn't quite work, I think jquery was still screwing with the output.  exa:  id=1[]=32&id[]=4&id=2[]=23&id[]=3&id[]=5&id[]=6  Thanks anyway, decided to just use toArray.

Comment: @Chris Lively - See the updated version, I think it solves your problem. After I posted the answer I went ahead and tested it, it didn't work with jQuery UI.